# posicionar en forma de U

Tags: css

Intento posicionar en forma de U los 3 elementos pero por alguna razon hay un espacio que los separa

me refiero a este espacio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.car {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.cara {
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.Loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.Back {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="cara"></div>
  <div class="Back">
    <div id="topForm"></div>
    <div id="bottomForm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pala">
  </div>
  <div class="Loader">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿A que espacio te refieres, al que hay entre .cara y .loader o a todo el espacio blanco en general?

Comment: @asantanao listo ya puse una imagen indicando cual es el espacio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres solo basta con invertir los valores de `width` y `height` que tienes en tu `div.cara` y manipular su posición `bottom`

```css
.car {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.cara {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.Loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.Back {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="cara"></div>
  <div class="Back">
    <div id="topForm"></div>
    <div id="bottomForm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pala">
  </div>
  <div class="Loader">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: el rectangulo negro (cara) debe ser mas pequeño

Comment: @hubman para hacerlo mas pequeño solo basta con modificar su valor de width, te he editado la respuesta !

Comment: mas pequeño no mas delgado

Comment: @hubman te he editado la respuesta, modificando su valor de height y su posicionamiento en bottom

Answer (score 3):

La altura del div con clase cara debería ser más alto, justo la mitad, al igual que el div con clase back. Si le pones `height=50px` divides el total del alto que es 100px en ambos.

```css
.car {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.cara {
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.Loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.Back {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="cara"></div>
  <div class="Back">
    <div id="topForm"></div>
    <div id="bottomForm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pala">
  </div>
  <div class="Loader">
  </div>

</div>
```

O, en caso de que el cuadrado tenga que ser del tamaño que tienes en el ejemplo, el contenedor debe ser menos alto, y la otra cara (back) tambien tiene que tener menos altura.

```css
.car {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
}

.cara {
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.Loader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.Back {
  width: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="cara"></div>
  <div class="Back">
    <div id="topForm"></div>
    <div id="bottomForm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pala">
  </div>
  <div class="Loader">
  </div>

</div>
```